# Ionic 2 Variable isn't showing in view

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm having some trouble with Angular 2(I'm new at it). My Ionic app doesn't recognize my array. Whenever I try to access the properties from may arry or object, ionic 2 says that my variable is empty. 
This is my code:
[image]
My "view":

And this is my controller showItem.ts:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the SO. Please include the code within the question itself rather than linking to an image of the code.

Comment: can you show us the format of your datax to further help with your problem.

Comment: Well you are nowhere inserting values to `book`?

Comment: I Found the problem... it is a known bug from angular. Angular needs to know the type of object is returning. In my case, I don't know why, but my return from ajax call was casting into a Object inside a Object. I just wanted 1 object and I'll show how I solved my problem. Thank you all, guys. Sorry for my post with print screen, it's my first time here and I didn't know how to show my code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your book type of `any` see if your data get assigned to book first:

```
book: any = [];
```

Also when you pushing data into book, try using `this.book` instead of passing the `this` into the function.

```
this.book.push({id:obj.id, title: obj.title, imagem: obj.imagem});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was into my provider. Actually, it's kinda of a bug that I have to cast into just one object. My json was returning a Object Inside a object. I solved this problem by casting my res.json() into my object name: "book". Like this: res.json()['book']

```
    buscarLivro(id)
    {
      if (this.dataBook) 
      {
        return Promise.resolve(this.dataBook);
      }
      // Dont have the data yet
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/books/'+id)
          .map(res => res.json()['book'])
          .subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.dataBook = data;
            resolve( this.dataBook);
          });
      });
    }
```

Comment: Just saying, you have gotten this wrong, you are not *casting* anything here. What you are doing is stepping into the JSON and extracting the data you need instead of assigning the complete response, i.e extracting the content of `book`, NOT casting anything. And no, this is absolutely NOT a bug. ;) ;)

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's true. I've seen somewhere that this problem was a bug but your explanation makes a lot more sense than that. Thank you!